# MySQL replacement for sum(if(xxx,1,0))

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

Hi I need some help optimizing this code, currently it takes 38 seconds to run the SQL query, and 23 to load it as a view. 
Here's the background - 
Redirects table records when a member uses a link and records where they go, and when they return and with what status.
Projects table manages the per project information that I need.
Currently I do have a third table that keeps a per project count which is updated each time a record is added to the redirects table, however the counts can be a little unreliable. Every hour the server runs the query to fix/verify the counts.

Is there any good way to count the columns without having to use a sum(if(xxx,1,0)) ?

```
Select projects.ID as ID,cid,name as name,state as status,
                sum(if(status="complete",1,0)) as complete,cpc,
                cpc*ss as mmkingaku,
                cpc*sum(if(status="complete",1,0)) as total,
                sum(if(status="screenout",1,0)) as screenout,
                sum(if(status="quotafull",1,0)) as quotafull, 
                sum(if(status="short",1,0)) as short,
                sum(if(status="gate",1,0)) as gate,
                sum(if(status is null,1,0)) as empty,
                sum(if(status="complete",1,0))/(sum(if(status="complete",1,0))+sum(if(status="screenout",1,0)))*100 as IR
                from redirects,projects
                where redirects.rid=projects.rid and state<>"test" group by name order by cid desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL performance is not usually due to calculations in the `select` clause.  You need to look at the `from` and `group by` clauses.

Do your tables have appropriate indexes?  You should have an index on `redirects.rid`, `projects.rid`, or both.  In fact, these should probably be composite indexes, including `state` and `test` (wherever is appropriate).

The `group by` can be a performance hog in MySQL.  How much data is in each table?

Comment: The data is quite large, the redirects table gets about 200k to 300k records per month, but the projects only gets about 30. -- projects.rid is uniquely indexed, redirects.rid is indexed. I'll index state now and I made an error in the code above (not on my server) it should be state<>"test"

Comment: After indexing, the script takes 20 seconds as opposed to the 30 seconds previously mentioned.

Comment: My guess is that the bulk of the effort is in the filesort for the `group by`.  You can see this using `explain`.  You don't seem to have any filtering that would significantly reduce the size of the data.  If this is important you might need to create a summary table that you keep up-to-date with triggers.

Comment: That seems to be the case. Is there no optimization to make this work better with out needing an additional table?